# Computing the gravitational force on a planet in a particular system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

I have a system of four planets moving in a 2D plane. I'm trying to write some code (C++) to find the positions of these planets at time t=3.

[image: System information]

I'm probably going to attempt this via a leapfrog integrator, though I'm open to suggestion. It seems I'm going to have to compute the acceleration of each planet, and to do this I'll use $F_i=m_ia_i$ and $F_i = \sum_{j\neq i} \frac{Gm_im_j}{r^2} $ where $i$ and $j$ denote particular planets.

I'm a bit confused about how I compute that gravitational force though in this case; I'm pretty rusty on the physics. Some sources suggest $$F_i = \sum_{j\neq i} \frac{Gm_im_j}{((x_{0_i}-x_{0_j})^2+(x_{1_i}-x_{1_j})^2)^{3/2}}\sqrt{(x_{0_j}-x_{0_i})^2+(x_{1_j}-x_{1_i})^2} $$
But really I'm pretty confused. Another issue I'm having, is how I'm going to compute the acceleration in the $x$ direction and acceleration in the $y$ direction separately.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: To get the $x$ component of the force, replace that square root term with $(x_{0_j}-x_{0_i})$ and similarly for the $y$ component.

Comment: Outside of that, is that the formula I should use to compute the sum of all the forces on a given planet $i$?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct equation.

Comment: Note that you don't really have a question here. You state (twice) that you are confused, *but not what you are confused about*. If you write up what you are confused about and ask a question, I'll be willing to nominate this for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *magnitude* of the force between $i$ and $j$ is indeed
$$ F_{ij} = \frac{Gm_im_j}{\lvert\vec{r}_{ij}\rvert^2}. $$
The *direction* of this vector is directed along the line connecting the two points, the same as $\vec{r}_{ij}$ (my notation for the vector difference between the positions of $i$ and $j$). In principle you can compute the magnitude for each pair and decompose the result into an amount in each direction using trig functions.

In practice, the trig functions are unnecessary (you'd be taking trig functions of inverse trig functions anyway). The vector force on $i$ due to $j$ can be written
$$ \vec{F}_{ij} = \frac{Gm_im_j}{\lvert\vec{r}_{ij}\rvert^2} \frac{\vec{r}_{ij}}{\lvert\vec{r}_{ij}\rvert} = \frac{Gm_im_j}{\lvert\vec{r}_{ij}\rvert^3} \vec{r}_{ij}. $$ So the total force on $i$ has components
\begin{align}
F_i^1 & = \sum_{j\neq i} \frac{Gm_im_j}{(x_j-x_i)^2+(y_j-y_i)^2)^{3/2}} (x_j-x_i) \\
F_i^2 & = \sum_{j\neq i} \frac{Gm_im_j}{(x_j-x_i)^2+(y_j-y_i)^2)^{3/2}} (y_j-y_i).
\end{align}
You should of course divide through by $m_i$ to get the accelerations.

And yes, leapfrog is an excellent choice for this sort of thing, as I [push on everyone](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/what-is-the-correct-way-of-integrating-in-astronomy-simulations) every chance I get. Euler integration will send your planets flying off unphysically quite rapidly, and you have to be really careful when using non-symplectic integrators like Runge-Kutta -- these trade long-term stability for short-term accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response. If I understand it correctly, using the equations for $F_i^1$ and $F_i^2$ exactly as they are there, I have no need for a trigonometric component? 
I think the force acts along the line between the two planets, $i$ and $j$, but when we split it into components for the $x$ and $y$ directions does this negate the need for the trig function taking the angle of the force into account?

Comment: In a system like this, should I expected the planets to have a concentric (or near enough) orbit, circular or elliptical in shape? Or in the case of 4 planets in an isolated system like this are they likely to have more exotic looking orbits? 
I want to have an idea what to expect when I run the code so I'll have an idea if I've made a mistake, cheers.

Comment: The trigonometry vanishes here because of relations like $\cos(\tan^{-1}(\Delta y/\Delta x)) = \Delta x / \sqrt(\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2). As for the orbits, they will definitely be nothing like circles. For one, you haven't included a central star dominating the gravity. For another, the initial velocities aren't pointing along circular paths around the origin (where the star presumably would be). Really, this setup is more of a miniature globular cluster than a solar system.

Comment: In addition to the chaos, though, there's a question of if the system is bound. The potential energy between a pair of objects is $-Gm_im_j/r$. Sum this over all pairs. The kinetic energy for each object is $m_iv_i^2/2$. Sum this over all objects. If the total energy is positive, the system is unbound and at least one object will fly off to infinity, never to return.

Comment: Thanks, I may compute the potential and kinetic energies to check if the system is bounded if I encounter issues over larger times. I looked at your link on integrators, your response to another question, and you address the next issue I'm having; how to compute $v_\frac{1}{2}$. 
Would I be correct in saying that this is an appropriate formula for working out $v_\frac{1}{2}$ ? 
$$v_\frac{1}{2} = v_0 + \frac{h}{2}a_0$$

Comment: Yes, that formula should work fine.